# Can Java's regex engine be made to forbid variable length lookbehind?

Tags: java, regex

Starting with Java 9, the regex engine began supporting variable-length lookbehind. I guess that's great and all if you want it, but that's a really good way to make a regex that is vulnerable to ReDOS attacks, or just being accidentally ReDOSsed by ordinary user input.

For reasons that are beyond the scope of this question, I am unable to police the regexes that my application is using to the extent that I'd like. We've had problems with regexes *that wouldn't even have compiled* in ancient versions of Java, but instead are causing application hangs (when a clean failure would have been much preferred).

I'm guessing the answer is "no", but is there any way to get like legacy behavior on the Java regex engine, or to otherwise enable stricter checking, so that pathological regexes like this won't even be compiled by the engine? It would be much better to just fail these regexes, than for it to work most of the time but then if you give it just the right input it hangs.

Edit to add: So there's stuff like [this open source project](https://github.com/NicolaasWeideman/RegexStaticAnalysis) that would maybe be something to look at if I decide I need to analyze any new regexes to make sure they aren't Evil. It would be nice if there was just a "strict" setting on the regex engine or something tho...

Comment: "Strict" is nebulous, though. If you know the specific regexes that are problematic is identifying them that difficult? Variable length lookbehind seems ok to identify, but haven't dug at all.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm really not too offended by Blindy's comment lol. These regexes are really not good, and regex might even be the wrong tool for the job here.  "Stupid" might just be a harsh-but-fair characterization of the situation :sweating-intensifies: 

And I mean that's probably what we'll do, is just tell the people who made these regexes "don't do that", and explain why.

Comment: That involves scheduling a meeting tho. The horror.

Comment: How are regexes that exponentially backtrack handled?  I would think they would cause the same issue.

Comment: @WJS those are all salient questions and kinda gets at the truly "correct" answer to my question -- which is "don't do it that way" lol.  _If_ there was some way to configure the Java regex engine to display legacy behavior, that would be a good short-term band-aid, which is all I was hoping for.  Medium-to-long term, yeah absolutely, we need to either a) move away from doing it this way, or b) explicitly screen the regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The introduction of variable-length lookbehind in Java 9 indeed made it more flexible but also potentially riskier to ReDoS attacks. If you're concerned about the safety of regexes in your application, you might need to implement your own regex validation or filtering mechanism.

As stated [here](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2631/), the ReDoS issue has been handled in Java 9 but is still vulnerable to ReDoS, just needs trickier patterns than a basic `(a|aa)+`. This problem will never go away. A regular expression engine like RE2, is by design immune to these exponential runtime problems, but they had to drop certain regular expression features to achieve this.

Comment: Provisionally accepting this answer, as I am increasingly sure this is what it comes down to: You either just don't make bad regexes, or else you have to do explicit analysis to screen your regexes.

Comment: basically yes, however a problem can be solved in other ways. regexes are not always needed. If poorly written they can cause problems, testing them well is always a good thing

Comment: Agreed. In the long term, I think regexes are fundamentally the wrong approach to the problem we are tackling here, and not just because of the danger of poorly written ones - the use case is not a great fit to begin with

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you would write or find an existing regex lexer which validates that a variable-width lookbehind does not exist.

Websites such as regex101 are clearly doing some sort of processing to show hover messages such as:

> A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width

https://regex101.com/r/X778hR/1

---

Likewise, languages which don't support variable-width lookbehinds will produce an error such as PHP:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 0

https://onlinephp.io/c/30d57

---

If you have the ability to bundle a regex flavor which does not support variable-width lookbehinds with your Java app then you **could** perform validation by invoking a non-Java regex flavor and checking for errors which you would then communicate to your end users.

---

Another option could be to make use of the PCRE library directly instead of relying on a separate programming language to talk to PCRE for you.

Comment: "Another option could be to make use of the PCRE library directly instead of relying on a separate programming language to talk to PCRE for you."

Looks like our short-term solution is to tell the people making the regexes to validate them on regex101.com _and make sure PCRE2 is selected as the flavor_. So yeah, sorta the poor-man's version of this.

Comment: @user435779 I can only assume lookbehinds aren't the root problem though and your users are simply bad at regex and do things like catastrophic backtracking and inefficient nightmares. Exposing them to regex101 is a great step in the right direction all around.